# How to create new data row field with unknown data type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

The question title is phrased poorly, so here's some background:

I'm using reflection to create a `DataRow` within a `DataTable` that has fields with the property name, value and type of another object, although I'm at a loss of how to set the type correctly, the following hasn't pleased intellisense:

```
Application app = Get(id, context); // Method args provide these

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

foreach (PropertyInfo p in app.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    dr.SetField<p.PropertyType>(p.Name, p.GetValue(p, null)); // attempt 1
    dr.SetField<typeof(p.GetType())>(p.Name, p.GetValue(p, null)); // attempt 2
    dr.SetField<p.GetType()>(p.Name, p.GetValue(p, null)); // attempt 3
}

return dt;
```

Comment: No comment to accompany the down vote?

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but it would be wise to look at documentation regarding generics. And reflection in general as you may end up needing to dynamically invoke your `dr.SetField`.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember when using `Reflection` is that once you start using it, you have to go all the way using `Reflection`.

You can't specify a generic argument like that. You have to provide a type name. If you don't know the type name then you need to get [`SetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039(v=vs.110).aspx) method using `Reflection` and call it's `Invoke` method by providing a `DataRow` instance and the values.

As a hint once you get `SetField` method from `DataRowExtensions` you can  use [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to construct a generic method by providing a type instance (which is `p.PropertyType` in this case)